# How to get Knockout js foreach working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am creating a simple budget app to help me learn knockout js.

What I'm trying to do is allow a user to enter or load a JSON object representing a list of bills. The use can enter a date for their next payday and click the Week Range button. They can then enter new bills if desired but not necessary. This will generate an array that stores the date of the next payday. For now you just click the Get Bills button to populate the bills array from some hardcoded data. After that click the Set Budget button to process the weekRange array and the bills array. Where an object is created representing the bills for that week, which is then plugged in to a budget array.

Everything is working except when I try to begin displaying the budget array with a foreach binding it fails.

Please refer to this js fiddle for the code [Budget JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jokerfwb/0c3swuu6/)
Here is the function that process the bills and the weekRange arrays

```
self.setBudget = function () {
        self.budget.removeAll();
        for (var i = 0; i < self.weekRange().length; i++) {            
            var weekOf = self.weekRange()[i];
            var startDate = moment(weekOf);
            var endDate = moment(self.weekRange()[i + 1]);

            var thisWeeksBill = new weeklyBill();
            thisWeeksBill.startOfWeek(weekOf);       

            for (var j = 0; j < self.bills().length; j++) {
                var date = moment(self.bills()[j].dueDate());

                if (date.isBetween(startDate, endDate, null, '[)')) {  
                    var jsBill= ko.toJS(self.bills()[j]);
                    thisWeeksBill.weeklyBills().push(new bill(jsBill));                   
                    self.bills()[j].dueDate(date.add(1, 'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD"))                     
                }
            }
            thisWeeksBill.weeklyAmount(totalWeeklyBills(thisWeeksBill));
            self.budget().push(thisWeeksBill);             

        }
        console.log(self.budget());
    }
```

The html for the table with the foreach binding

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Week Of</td>            
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: budget">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="textinput: startOfWeek"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

If you pull up the dev tools and watch to console you will see that the weekRange array is populated after clicking the WeekRange button and the budget array is populated after clicking the Set Budget button, but nothing happens in the table that is suppose to (at the moment) just show a list of the weekly start dates.

Comment: is this correct? https://jsfiddle.net/0c3swuu6/19/ looks like you had some syntax errors on your pushes.

Comment: Wow thank you that appears to fix the issue. I didn't realize I didn't need to declare the open and closing parens on the parent node of the nested objects when doing a push.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Dellinger pointed out in the comments you had issues with `push`. I wouldn't say it's really a syntax error though—you really are pushing elements to the array. **The issue that you're modifying the underlying array, which doesn't trigger an update notification.** When you use `push` directly on the observable, though, knockout's function will trigger an update notification

> For functions that modify the contents of the array, such as push and splice, KO’s methods automatically trigger the dependency tracking mechanism so that all registered listeners are notified of the change, and your UI is automatically updated. [[1]](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

I haven't seen anywhere where it says explicitly that modifying the underlying object of an observable doesn't trigger the update, but that's the behavior. Using the `valueHasMutated()` function on the observable can force an update, though. So if you want to update the underlying array, perhaps to skip the update if you're doing many modifications and only want one update, then you can call that.